# Progress Bar in Excel using VBA and userForms

Tags: vba, excel

so I've been looking and cant find anything on this, I hope someone can help.

what I am trying to do:

I want to create a progress bar for my excel workbook that I am making. in order to accomplish this I have created a user form with data fields that I can manipulate from outside of the userform. what I would like to do is to load the userform from inside a module and then from the same module update the userform as the module continues to run.

is there a way to do this?

currently when I use `userForm1.Show` it displays the userform, but the control never goes back to the calling module, and the code ends when reaching the `End Sub` for `Private Sub userForm1_Activate()`

any help would be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: I created a class for my progress bar so I can call it whenever necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to show ProgressBar UserForms in VBA as modal or modeless?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169975/is-it-better-to-show-progressbar-userforms-in-vba-as-modal-or-modeless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the userform as a modal form. To return the control back to the calling module, you must open the userform modelessly:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```