# show multiple modal userforms in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I'm looking for a way to close and reopen multiple modal userforms via VBA, which previously were opened manually.

Opening both modal userforms manually works fine: The first userform was opened by clicking a button (activx) on a worksheet, the second userform is opend by clicking a button (commandbutton2) on the first userform.

In order to apply updates to the worksheet I need to close both userforms temporary. I tried the following code:

```
userform2.hide 'needs to be hidden before hiding the first userform, since both forms are modal
userform1.hide
userform1.show
userform2.show
```

This, of course, doesn't work properly since the code execution get [halted by forms that open modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783906/why-does-showing-a-userform-as-modal-stop-code-execution). Using `UserformX.show vbModeless` would allow the code to execute but it will also allow the user to access the worksheet without closing the forms which I don't want.

What would be a possible solution here?

EDIT: There is supposed to be a solution by using `Application.OnTime` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881520/2089396) unfortunately I couldn't get to work (assuming it works at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to open multiple cascaded modal userforms by using events (like activate etc.). This way showing the first modal form triggers the event which shows the second one etc.